# Windows application toolkit fails to remove UAC prompt on specific program

Tags: windows-7, uac, arduino-ide

OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

My Arduino IDE fails to open unless I "Run as administrator". If I don't,It will just show the loading screen:

[image]

but will not actually open up the IDE. I have been searching for ways that I could bypass this just for arduino.exe and have found that this could be done with Windows Application Compatibility toolkit as outlined [here](http://meridian.ws/wordpress/?p=306).

When I get to the test run part after checking runasinvoker as shown here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [meridian.ws](http://meridian.ws/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Figure-C.jpg))</sub>

Arduino started with no issues. But after I follow the rest of the steps and install the fix, my Arduino IDE program still has the same problem. If I do not run it as administrator, it will just show the loading splash screen and not the IDE part.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: The "run as invoker" option prevents Windows from asking you to elevate.  It doesn't magically make the program work without admin privilege.

Comment: I understand that, which is why I am assuming the guide directs us to check the "run as administrator" box under the compatibility tab. How would you recommend bypassing the prompt?

Comment: You can't bypass the prompt.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WcWJlm_O_k). It clearly shows that you can indeed bypass the prompt. Perhaps there was a misunderstanding in what I meant by "by pass the prompt"?

Comment: By "bypass the prompt" I supposed you wanted to run the program as admin without being prompted.  You can't do that.  The video shows you how to stop Windows from wanting to run a particular program as admin: you don't get prompted, and the program isn't given admin privilege.  (It isn't entirely clear to me whether the author of that video understands this or not.)  At any rate, it appears that the program you're trying to run *needs* admin privilege, so the "run as invoker" compatibility fix is counter-productive.

Comment: (You can of course turn off UAC altogether if you want to, but that's almost always a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this program does not support running as a standard user, you will not be able to fix that. The developers of the application need to fix it so that it runs correctly as a standard user.

People are confused by the UAC. Try running the same application on Windows XP.

It's possible that File and Registry Redirection is causing an issue, but i doubt it. You can disable *File and Registry Redirection* by adding an assembly manifest that includes the **runas invoker** section:

**Arduino.exe.manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <assemblyIdentity 
            version="1.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="X86"
            name="client"
            type="win32"
    /> 

    <description>Don't Arguino With Me</description> 

    <!-- Disable Windows Vista UAC compatability heuristics -->
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo> 

</assembly>
```

and place `arduino.exe.manifest` in the same folder as `arduino.exe`.

**Note**: Windows will only read an external assembly manifest file if there isn't already an assembly manifest resource inside the application. I doubt there already is one.

Best guess: this application must be run as an administrator, and that's the end of it (until they fix it)